# Develop SharePoint at home

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to develop Sharepoint in home. How can I do this? I tried Sharepoint Foundation but it says it can't be installed on my pc. And I can find any solution on the internet

Comment: what OS on your PC? SharePoint 2013 installation on win 7 or 8 not supported...so if you have win 8 pro then their is something you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows 8 PC which comes with Hyper-V, you can install the Hyper-V roles and provision server VM's to install SharePoint on. Your other option would be to buy a VMWorkstation license.

There are some guides out on the internet on how to "hack" SharePoint to make it run on a non-Server OS. That said, it's not a lifelike environment, so your development isn't really being done against a best practices SharePoint farm. If your environment isn't built to best practices, then you're basically developing as an admin on everything so you're not necessarily testing against an accurate security model. Think of it as being a Domain Admin all the time.

There also are Information Worker VM's available from Microsoft that come with SharePoint, Office, etc. installed and configured correctly. If you don't have the experience or background to install SharePoint using best practices, you may start there.